# Why there is not () {parantheses} in JavaScript function calling

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

This is a code snap of index.js file which is created by default in a new phonegap project.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

On line 11,

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

I assume that `this.onDeviceReady` is a function call so why there is no `()` like `this.onDeviceReady()` here?

Comment: It's not a function call, it's a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.onDeviceReady` is function reference here. When used `()` on function, it'll be called immediately.

When used function reference the function is passed to the other function and when some event occurs the function is called.

This is same as

```
function somefun(callback) {


    // When something ASYNCHRONOUS process completes, call the callback function
    callback();
}

var myFun = function() {
    console.log('in myFun');
};

function somefun(myFun);
```

Comment: @kashyapkotak Right.

Answer (score 1):

If we use () along with `this.onDeviceReady` while passing the function as reference, onDeviceReady() method will get immediately invoked.